# Entity Framework One to Many Relationship without PK

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two to be related entities as below :

```
public class VehicleExtraEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid NameKey { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WordEntity> WordsOfName { get; set; }
}
```

And the other entity :

```
public class WordEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Guid Key { get; set; }
}
```

My purpose is write multi language supported db tables. For example ;

```
WordEntity1 : {Id=1, Content="Child Seat", Key="abcdef-12456"}
WordEntity2 : {Id=2, Content="Çocuk Koltuğu", Key="abcdef-12456"} --> Same Key
VehicleExtraEntity1 : {Id=1, NameKey = "abcdef-123456"}
```

I have tried fluent api but that support only relationships with navigation property. And it wants to me use many to many relationship. But I want resolve my problem as I wrote as above.

Comment: Isn't it that the `WordEntity::Id` is a PK? And please show the fluent api code you have tried. If you are going to reuse the `WordEntity1` to another entity beside `VehicleExtraEntity`, why not using many to many?

Comment: yes WordEntity:Id is PK. I tried a lot of fluent api. The codes appears logical was not compiled :) . And the compiled fluent api codes creates "VehicleExtraEntity_Id" in WordEntities table. 
Many to many will be creates logical problem.

Comment: Does `WordEntity::Key` have unique constraint? And you want to use `VehicleExtraEntitiy::NameKey` to refer to `WordEntity::Key`? If that's what you meant, then you need to wait [EF7, unique constraint candidate key support](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support). So currently your options is to have ~`VehicleExtraEntity_Id` in `VehicleExtraEntity`.

Comment: Yes I exactly want `VehicleExtraEntity::NameKey` refer to `WordEntity::Key`

Comment: I meant, to have ~`WordEntity_Id` in `VehicleExtraEntity`.

Comment: Uh. Apparently I have to wait. Do you know when will be release ?

Comment: is there any reason you don't use the primary key of VehicleExtraEntity as the foreign key